# Function after Android Asynctask.execute()

Tags: android-asynctask

Just out of curiosity, if I have a function right after android's `Asyntask.execute()`, can this function be executed before `Asynctask`'s execution is completed?

Comment: It will get executed before AsyncTask's execution, in case you need to execute a function after completion, you need to use an interface to trigger function in onPostExecute() method of AsyncTask.

Comment: thanks for the info :) what if I have `Asynctask` in a loop and I want to work with values returned from the loop? See: [Looping over Android ListView items using Asynctask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39137012/looping-over-android-listview-items-using-asynctask)